# Getting error while install Magento 2.x

Tags: php, magento, server, localhost, php-extension

I tried to install Magento 2.x .But it gives an error **PHP Extensions Check** in  **PHP Extension intl**. I tried to install **intl** extension by removing the semicolon from php.ini file and then restart the server.But it still gives the same error.

Please tell me ,How to install **php_intl** PHP Extension on local server?

Comment: Can you please tell me which server you are using ? and you have to restart **apache** server not your system. I had same problem but i have remove semicolon and restart **apache** server the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps to solve the error

For Windows

1. Stop Wamp/Xampp services
2. Open Wamp/Xampp php.ini file
3. Remove semicolon (;) for the line
   ;extension=php_intl.dll
4. Restart your services

For Linux

1. Type command in terminal to install php intl extension
   sudo apt-get install php5-intl
2. Restart php fpm services by writing below command in terminal
   sudo service php5-fpm retsart